# Entity Framework mapping to DTO too slow

Tags: performance, entity-framework, dto

Entity Framework is building a SQL query that takes less than 2 seconds. Even though the query is ugly, it's fast. In the EF SELECT statementI'm building a DTO based on my entites. The DTO has around 20 properties and it's plain. So, EF is running a query that returns these 20 properties I need. Everything seems fine but building the DTO takes almost 10 seconds. I have already told EF not to track changes (AsNoTracking() over the db sets) so I'm not sure what's happening between the query is executed and the DTO is built.

What's EF doing under the hood that makes it so slow? Again, the query is fine and returns really fast but building the DTO with those properties is really slow.

I replaced this logic by a stored procedure that returns the same 20 properties and it is really, really fast. The DTO is the same so there has to be something in the middle, between reading the results of the query and building the DTO that is different.

I hope someone can help me figure out what's going on.

**EDIT:**

I'm adding how I'm populating the DTO based on a comment.

```
.Select(p => new PMPanelOffersDTO()
                                {
                                    OfferId = p.Id,
                                    OfferDate = p.DateCreated,
                                    UserId = p.UserId,
                                    OfferAmountId = p.AmountId,
                                    OfferAmountTypeId = p.Amount != null ? p.Amount.OfferType.Id : default(int?),
                                    OfferAmountType = p.Amount != null ? p.Amount.OfferType.Name : null,
                                    TowerCompanyName = p.Amount != null && p.Amount.Tower != null ? p.Amount.Tower.CompanyName : null,
```

... { the same for the other properties }

Comment: Can you show the code populating your dto?

Comment: I have just added a few lines of code describing how I'm populating the DTO.

Comment: Profile the app and post the profile. Or, pause the debugger 10 times. What code is running most often?

Comment: start removing properties out of the dto object initializer. see if it's a problem with those.

Comment: I confirm that the problem is not any specific property. I don't have EF source code integrated in my project so I cannot profile what's going on under EF's hood.

Comment: Is there anything happening before the select? Does `.Select(p => p)` yield the same effect?

Comment: Nothing happens before the ".Select".

Comment: a funny thing happened to us in the same situation... I added .ToList() to the end of the query and I literally gained 90% of my time back

Answer (score 0):

Do you apply paging? (I mean skip&take) And most importantly where exactly ToList() is used?
We have exactly the same problem, solved in a such a way that use ToList() after DTO construction.

Comment: We don't use paging for this page because we need to show all the information without pagination, that's a business requirement. 
The ToList() is applied a few lines of code below but that shouldn't make any difference because the query is not executed until you call ToList() (that's because EF works with deferred execution). We build the DTO, apply sorting and then we call ToList() in 3 different lines of code. 
We are returning around 1,500 DTO objects, it shouldn't take 7 sec. to build them. After switching to a SP, it takes less than 1 sec. to build the DTOs using EF.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .ToList() on the resulting object. That's all it took in our case. I agree it made no sense. Apparently the IEnumerable<> was not a happy thing

Comment: If you do ToList() before building the DTO you will be retrieving a lot of data that you don't need.